# knife ssl check fails wile connecting to manage chef.io

Tags: linux, ubuntu, devops, chef-infra, knife

```
root@ip-172-31-9-21:/home/ubuntu/chef-repo# knife ssl check
/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/proxifier-1.0.3/lib/uri/socks.rb:8:in `<modu                                                              le:URI>': uninitialized class variable @@schemes in URI (NameError)
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/proxifier-1.0.3/lib/uri/socks.r                                                              b:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir                                                              e.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir                                                              e.rb>:85:in `require'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/proxifier-1.0.3/lib/proxifier.r                                                              b:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir                                                              e.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir                                                              e.rb>:85:in `require'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.0.185/lib/chef/mixin/pr                                                              oxified_socket.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir                                                              e.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir                                                              e.rb>:85:in `require'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.0.185/lib/chef/knife/s                                                              sl_check.rb:33:in `block in <class:SslCheck>'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.0.185/lib/chef/knife.r                                                              b:245:in `each'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.0.185/lib/chef/knife.r                                                              b:245:in `load_deps'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.0.185/lib/chef/knife.r                                                              b:230:in `run'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.0.185/lib/chef/applica                                                              tion/knife.rb:165:in `run'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.0.185/bin/knife:24:in                                                               `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/bin/knife:400:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/knife:400:in `<main>'
```

please help me to solve this error.

Comment: uninitialized class variable @@schemes in URI (NameError) <= I guess the url you set in your knife.rb or config.rb is wrong.